# How to work/loop through multiple collections dependent on one another in mongo db using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I just want to `update` the data in NewOrder Collection and then do some operations on array data but this returns below error.

```
req.body contains the only array of _id of documents like [ 
'5e70bf169d79bb0e94633886',  '5e70bf169d79bb0e94633888']` 
TypeError: response.products.forEach is not a function
    at C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\api\routes\neworders.js:89:45
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
GET /ords/?page=1&limit=20 200 1606.706 ms - 5046
(node:1172) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0-shard-00-02-wv4bu.mongodb.net
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\serverSelection.js:22:11)
    at Function.Model.$wrapCallback (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4846:32)
    at C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4345:21
    at C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4344:10)
    at C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\api\routes\peginate.js:11:49
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Navin\Desktop\Angular Projects\node-rest-shop\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)`
```

The code that produces this bug is:

```
router.post('/cancel/', (req, res, next) => {
  const data = req.body;
  console.log(data);
        var tempArray = [];
          data.forEach(order=> {
              NewOrder.updateOne({_id: order}, { $set : {
                    order_status: "cancelled",
                    paid_amount: 0
              }}).exec().then( result => {
                        NewOrder.findById(order)
                        .exec()
                        .then(response => {
                          response.products.forEach(product => {
                              let item = {
                                _id: product.prod_id,
                                quantity: product.req_quantity
                              }
                              tempArray.push(item);
                          });
                        })
                        .catch( err=> {
                          console.log(err);
                        });

              })
              .catch( err => {
                console.log(err);
              });    
          });
          tempArray.forEach( element => {
               console.log( element);
          });
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Finished operation"
          });
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple Null pointer. You are assuming that `response.products` is not null.

You need to test `if(response && response.products)` exists, before trying to iterate on the products array.